# Как перевести "beat that"?

Tags: перевод, выбор-слова, сленг, idioms

Как перевести на русский разговорное восклицание "beat that!"  Это сокращение от "Can you beat that?" Выражение может быть использовано в процессе игры или неформального соревнования. Вот пара ситуаций:

> The teenager scored 15 points on a basketball court. Exclaimed "beat that!" and passed the ball to his friend.
>
> -- I got 95% on math test. Beat that!

Перевод "попробуй перебей!" звучит искуственно притянуто.

Comment: «попробуй перебей» звучит не искусственно, оно просто имеет другой смысл ("try to interrupt!")

Comment: "Попробуй переплюнь" звучит лучше. Можно ещё "СлабО?"

Comment: "А ты смогёшь?" (Не очень литературно, но все же.)

Comment: Может быть "сможешь лучше?"?

Comment: Нет, "перебить" также имеет значение "overbid", так что по смыслу подходит, хотя и не вполне.

Comment: "«попробуй перебей» звучит не искусственно, оно просто имеет другой смысл ("try to interrupt!")" - это зависит лишь от того - что имеется ввиду под "перебей"в этой игре, и в этом контексте. Это не обязательно должно означать именно "перебить в разговоре", нет.  Если там надо что-то сбивать и бить...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выражение "побить рекорд" используется до сих пор. Понятно, что смысл -- "сделать лучше". Конкретный перевод зависит от вкусов переводчика. Один из вариантов: "Можешь так?".

Comment: Как насчет "Слабо?"

Comment: @Artemix: I am sure there will be at least a few more. In a sense, the question cannot be answered without knowing the *exact* context.

Answer (score 13):

Я бы перевёл "Слабо?" или "Выкуси!".

Answer (score -2):

I would translate this as:

> Ваш ход (шахматы)
>
> Ваша очередь (другие виды спорта)