# Что означает выражение "Кому не слабо"?

Tags: значения

Каково значение выражения "Кому не слабó"?

Comment: «Кому під силу».

Comment: Спасибо большое. А то читаю русские страницы в нете и все не мог понять что они имеют в виду.

Comment: Извините @Artemix, не понял?

Comment: Ну может таг перепутал - наверное таг нужен не "перевод", а "значение". Я знаю русский язык на среднем уровне и хотел узнать что значит выражение "Кому не слабó". Оно часто изспользуется в коментариях.
В таком случае как правильно было задать вопрос, @Artemix?

Comment: Я бы предложил: в каком значении употребляется оборот "А не слабо"? (В этом случае ударение ставить не нужно, оно однозначно на последнем слоге). Пример на иное ударение: [`― Не слабо солярка у вас стоит, ― усмехнулся Елтышев`](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E5%20%F1%EB%E0%E1%EE&docid=20793)

Comment: Спасибо, ето я скопировал с коментария (на то и ударение поставлено). Да, чаще всего встречается "А Вам не слабо?".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Слаб́о` это предикат, то есть, выступает как сказуемое, отвечает на вопросы `кому? что?`. 
`Сл́або` это краткое прилагательное от `слабый`.

Точное значение вопроса `Слаб́о?`: `Можешь?`
К этому значению необходимо добавить подтекст: *давай, покажи нам, что ты не слабак, не трус, не размазня.*

The word `Слаб́о` is a word in the short predicative form.

The precise meaning of the question `Слаб́о?` is `Can you do it?`.
Then in any language we must add a connotation value for it: *Show us that you are not a cream puff, worrier or not a weakling one.*

Comment: У кого английский как второй родной, поправьте, пожалуйста, в коннотации, если есть необходимость.

Comment: See also this post: [Как перевести "Beat that!"](http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/8129/551)

Comment: Я согласен с ответом, @Avtokod, но возникает второй вопрос, в Вашем коментарие на мой вопрос Вы привели пример, я так понимяю, что там `Не слабо ...` имеется в виду дорог. Я правильно понял?

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov , да, Вы правильно поняли. Откуда это возникло? Мы говорим: `сильно дорого, сильно дёшево`=`очень дорого, очень дёшево`. Но нигде не услышите `слабо дорого, слабо дешево`. Я предполагаю, что изобретательные носители языка пользуются в разговоре необычным звучанием, которое возникает, если отрицать усиление. Пример: `Не сл́або это стоит, однако.` Отмечу, что это исключительно разговорный стиль.

Comment: Спасибо @Avtokod, у меня как раз проблема с разговорной части языка. Я русский понимаю, но как речь идет об разговорной части, иногда как говорится `ни бельмеса не понимяю` :)